# Writing natural-looking abbreviations

Tags: правописание, сокращения

I'm making electronic slides for a presentation, and sometimes the Russian words are too long to easily fit, so I'd like to use some abbreviations. In lectures on blackboards, I've seen abbreviations like ф-я for функция, д-во for доказательство, and ст-рa for структура.

When I showed a sample of my slides to a native speaker, she thought удов-яют for удовлетворяют (built on the pattern of the previous examples) looked weird, and that удов. looked more natural. She thought there may be a preference to abbreviate verbs using only the initial letter, and nouns and adjectives using the initial and final letters, although she hasn't really done this herself in making slides (and this convention isn't always followed, e.g., Теор. for Теорема instead of Теор-а).

My basic request is for advice on how to write natural-looking abbreviations of long Russian words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот текст с сайта TheRules.ru пропущенный через мой личный опыт:

1. Предпочитаю использовать для сокращения точку (**.**) вместо дефиса (-), там, где это возможно. Это позволяет избежать странных слов.
2. Начальная буква может быть любая, но первая буква после дефиса, всегда согласная: о-во (общество), д-р (доктор), т-во (товарищество), б-ка (библиотека).
3. Нельзя сокращать на гласную букву, только если она не в начале слова, и на букву «ь». Например: слово карельский может быть сокращено: **к.**, **кар.**, **карельск.**, а не в виде ка., каре., карель.,
4. При стечении двух одинаковых согласных сокращение следует делать после первой согласной,например: **стен.** календарь, **грам.** ошибка (а не стенн., грамм.). При стечении двух различных или нескольких согласных сокращение следует делать после последней согласной, например: **народн.** творчество (а не народ.), **русск.** язык (а не рус.), **искусств.** шёлк (а не искус., или искусс., или искусст.).
5. Есть список, так называемых, общепринятых сокращений. Например: 
   и т. д. — и так далее;
   и т. п. — и тому подобное;
   и др.   — и другие (после перечисления);
   и пр.   — и прочие;
   см. — смотри;
   ср. — сравни (при ссылке; например, на другую часть сочинения);
   напр.   — например;
   в., вв. — век, века (при обозначении цифрами веков);
   г., гг. — год, годы (при обозначении цифрами годов);
   т., тт. — том, томы;
   н. ст.  — новый стиль;
   ст. ст. — старый стиль;
   н. э.   — нашей эры;
   г.  — город;
   обл.    — область;
   р.  — река;
   оз. — озеро;
   о.  — остров;
   гр. — гражданин;
   стр.    — страница;
   акад.   — академик;
   доц.    — доцент;
   проф.   — профессор;
   ж. д.   — железная дорога;
   ж.-д.   — железнодорожный;
   им. — имени;

а также:
гор.    — город;
пос.    — посёлок;
ост.    — остановка;
ст.     — станция;
вх.     — входящий (-ая, ие);
исх.    — исходящий (-ая, ие);

По этому списку видно, что правилом 1 пользуюсь не только я.

Сокращения вроде «ф-я» встречались мне только в записях лекций. Для записей лекций подобные сокращения вполне допустимы, так как позволяют производить запись с нужной скоростью.

Кроме того есть сокращения типа: н/д (нет данных), об образовании которых ничего не могу сказать по существу.

Comment: Я имел в виду только сокращения в лекциях.

Comment: Я имел ввиду только сокращения в лекциях, записанных студентами. В студенческих записях могут быть абсолютно странные конструкции, главное чтобы пишущий понимал это. Такие лекции скорее похожи на шифр. В лекциях записанных на доске обычно применяют правила, которые я указал выше. Исключение составляет разве что «ф-я». И то это можно сократить до «ф.».

«Доказательство», например, у нас сокращали до «Д.». Слово «паралелльный» записывали как «||».

Сокращения на лекциях (на доске или в тетради) так или иначе образуются по правилам, которые я написал. Остальное — индивидуально.

Comment: Думаю "н/д" есть калька с N/A (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N/a)  (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/N/A)

Comment: Точно не могу сказать. Бывшие в употреблении же пишут как б/у, или санузел пишут как с/у.

Answer (score 1):

[This document](http://artlib.osu.ru/Docs/gost/7.12-93.pdf) can help you.
Also, try to save the parts of words that contain the main information. In this case *ф-я* looks bad — I would use *фун.*; and using *теор-а* doesn't make sense — you gain almost nothing from it, *теор.* is definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic rules to follow, and a thousand complex ones.

The basic rules are:

1. The abbreviated word should be understandable to the reader. Thus, commonly known abbreviations are preferred. Try this [ru.wiktionary.org](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C:%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) link, or this [slovari.ru](http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?p=266) one if you're not sure about your abbreviation.
2. Abbreviations should be unambiguous within your context. For example, if you say "фил.", I'm not too sure if you actually mean "философский" (филос.) or "филологический" (филол.).

For complex rules and more abbreviations, see [the link](http://artlib.osu.ru/Docs/gost/7.12-93.pdf) provided by @КуЪ in [his answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/1532/1264). It seems to cover a lot of rules and provides a good deal of examples.

Comment: your second example is actually no that good. Though `фил` abbreviation leads to disambiguation, it is far more likely to encounter `филфак` , and `филос.` and `филол.` can hardly be considered as widely accepted forms.

Comment: One more rule of thumb not related to ambiguity would be that abbreviation should preferably be cut so that the last remaining letter (sound) is a consonant (like фил., филос., or философ. for философский), and (less strict rule) if there is a hyphen, the part after hyphen should start with a consonant (like ф-ция for функция, and респ-ка for республика).

Comment: @farfareast It can happen to anybody. By the way, shabunc is right: филфак is a common abbreviation for both.

Comment: @Viridianus: Strictly speaking Oleg discusses фил. (Note: with dot) vs филол. and филос. - not филфак as one word. Oleg does not mention факультет word at all. It could be in the context "филол. обр-ние". So it is not necessarily a bad example. Btw. if we are speaking about word филфак, in my mind (and I believe for majority of others) it is fully connected to филологический факультет. I do not know how poor philosophers shorten the name of their faculty :-). I think the OP was about ad-hoc abbreviations. Such words as филфак are already first class citizen words by themselves.